# randomly select an item from IEnumerable by guid

Tags: c#, random, guid

Given the following lookup data, how can one randomly select one of these items based on guid? Most of the questions out there are based on some number.

```
IEnumerable<Widgets> _widgetSources = new List<Widgets>
{
    new() { Descr = "w1", TypeGuid = 'A878273827-A344-2323-34343-2E07A1BF93},
    new() { Descr = "w2", TypeGuid = 'A878273827-A345-2323-34343-234343E07A1BF93' },
    new() { Descr = "w3", TypeGuid = 'A878273827-A346-2323-34343-234343E07A1BF93' },
    new() { Descr = "w4", TypeGuid = 'A878273827-A347-2323-34343-234343E07A1BF93' },
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean based on guid? If you just want to select a random item, you could simply generate a Random integer between 0 and the (length of the List - 1) and select the item at that index in your list.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I get "weak number generator" as my list above has 4 items. Will keep playing with it to see how to sort it out

Comment: as long as you are selecting one item from a group of four, you’re never going to be able to randomize the selection to achieve more than a 1/4 chance of landing on any given result. Doesn’t matter how complex you make the randomizer, anyone can attempt to guess the chosen result with a 25% probability of success.